# Is there a way to move a node up the root in HOCON?

Tags: java, config, typesafe, hocon

I'm using typesafe config and I'm looking for an easy way to allow optional overrides of properties in config files that are shared between applications.

So lets say I have 2 apps, A & B. They both make use of a module Z. They both load a shared config file 'shared.conf'.

Module Z has a property defined in it's reference.conf

```
z.foo=bar
```

I'd like to be able to

```
#override the property for both A & B
z.foo=zap
```

or

```
#override the property for just A
a.z.foo=zip
```

I know I can do this for just the 'z' prefix in the application.conf of each app. e.g.

```
z = ${?a.z}
```

but I was hoping there might be a way to move all the way to the root node. e.g.

```
MAGICAL_ROOT = ${?a}
```

Is what I'm hoping for possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at the config github repository, the way to lift up a sub tree to the root, is not in configuration itself, but in the code.

I'll quote:

> You can also use withFallback to merge in some hardcoded values, or to "lift" a subtree up to the root of the configuration; say you have something like:
>
> ```
> foo=42
> dev.foo=57
> prod.foo=10
> ```
>
> Then you could code something like:
>
> ```
> Config devConfig = originalConfig
>                     .getConfig("dev")
>                     .withFallback(originalConfig)
> ```

In your case, you want something like:

```
Config aConfig = originalConfig
                    .getConfig("a")
                    .withFallback(originalConfig)
```

You can read more about [Merging config trees](https://github.com/lightbend/config#merging-config-trees).

Comment: This still appears to only be able to set Z.  I wanted (and would still like) to be able to lift arbitrary keys to the root level.

Comment: Thanks @ProgrammingGuy. I didn't understand your question correctly. I've updated my post.

Comment: @ProgrammingGuy, does that help you?

Comment: It might, the next time I'm setting up project config I'll try something along those lines and see how it goes.